# How to save user credentials in my cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

How do i store app's password in my mobile?I want to store my mobile app's password.i want stay logged in even i close the app. if i reopen the app home page must be opened.I  must not be   asked to login..I am using Apache cordova as my development platform.I have tried that using cordova secure storage plugin..but that is of no use.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i get the solution i tried local storage its work

i tried like this to save user credentials

```
                   `window.localStorage.setItem("key", username);
                    var keyname = window.localStorage.key(0);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("key2", password);
                    var keyname2 = window.localStorage.key(0);`
```

and to get the saved credentials

```
        var username = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
        var password = window.localStorage.getItem("key2");
```

Comment: Never ever try to save sensitive data in local storage. Use keychain instead